# three.js apply texture on object face without interruption

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having trouble to correctly apply a texture on object.

As you can see from this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WpP4.png the texture is repeated and not applied continuously across whole the front face of the object.

Here: http://goo.gl/Dx6hDI you can find the code and a live example.

someone can help me ?

Comment: Your object does not have correct UV coordinates. Load the object into a 3d editor, apply the coordinates you want, then export new version.

Comment: Thanks, it was the right information to solve my problem ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object does not have correct UV coordinates. Load the object into a 3d editor, apply the coordinates you want, then export new version.